# Calling Variables Dynamically in R

Tags: r

I am essentially trying to do the equivalent of a lookup. Here's what I have so far:

```
Hotel   Rate1   Rate2   Rate3   Rate4   Season
Hotel1  225     205     250     155     Rate2
Hotel2  175     165     180     175     Rate1
Hotel3  160     210     210     225     Rate3
Hotel4  230     210     200     150     Rate2
Hotel5  180     160     175     165     Rate4
```

As you can see, I've already gotten it to spit out the name of the variable it should be, now I'm looking for a way to get it to spit out the value that corresponds to that variable name, like this:

```
Hotel   Rate1   Rate2   Rate3   Rate4   Season  Exp.Rate
Hotel1  225     205     250     155     Rate2     205
Hotel2  175     165     180     175     Rate1     175
Hotel3  160     210     210     225     Rate3     210
Hotel4  230     210     200     150     Rate2     210
Hotel5  180     160     175     165     Rate4     165
```

I've done some Google Searching and, I've tried playing around with eval(as.name), but I can't quite find anything that does exactly what I'm looking for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a `row/column` indexing approach to extract the values.  Create a column index with `match`, `cbind` using the sequence of rows, and get the values of subset of dataset ('df1[2:5]`) that corresponds to the index and assign it to 'Exp.Rate'

```
df1$Exp.Rate <- df1[2:5][cbind(1:nrow(df1), match(df1$Season, names(df1)[2:5]))]
df1$Exp.Rate
#[1] 205 175 210 210 165
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer did the trick, though I don't fully understand how it worked. I get the match portion of the code, but what was the first part doing, particularly the 'cbind(1:nrow(df1),'?

Comment: @SeanJohns The `1:nrow(df)` is the sequence of rows, and when we cbind the row index with the column index got by `match`, we are saying to extract the element from the 1st row, 2nd column (205), and similarly for 2nd, i.e. it 2nd row, 1st column (as we are only checking with the 2nd to 5th column) and so on